# Kafka Streams aggregating historical and live events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a kafka streams application which is doing some aggregations (hourly counts) based on the event time. This works fine with live streaming data. 
Is there a way to also calculate historical data (historical hourly counts) based on a different input topic? 
What I've currently facing is kafka streams ignoring events from hours already closed. Historical imports are a one time job to produce a history of data. Once those are processed, the live events should be the source of processing.

Comment: If you start a new application (ie with different `application.id`) in parallel that processed the history topic, it should just work.

Comment: Hi Matthias, yes thats true. I did not mention that I've the requirement to import old data tenant based dynamically. So some older data will need to be processed when the application is running for a while. My idea to solve this, is to calculate the hourly counts for historical data by putting them into another topic and using the hour in the key. That way I do not use the window functions but just groupByKey and aggregation.

Comment: Well. The problem will be that data will never expire for this case and your local state store will grow unbounded. Does not seem like a good solution. In general, the pattern you have is hard to work with in a single application. What does prevent you to do it with a second app in parallel (ie, each time you need to import all data, you start a new app in parallel, do the processing, and stop the app afterwards)?

Comment: The problem I face is that I need to process historic data and streaming data in one application. Doing this with an Application which I need to start and stop would be too much effort as this has to be done thousands of times (not just once). 
But I don't get your comment why local state store grows infinite if you do `stream.groupByKey.count().toStream.to(topic)` where stream contains only imported data. Maybe I missed something crucial.

Comment: Well, if you import data with old timestamps (and use the timestamp in the key), you generate more and more keys (as it would be different timestamps each time you import some old data). And a regular KTable (ie, non-windowed KV-store) does not have any expiration capabilities.

Comment: What I've done is partioning the incoming data. The data with event-time < current hour is considered as imported data. The other events are considered as live streaming data. The timestamp I use for the key of grouping the imported data is the truncated hour of the event time. So this should not grow infinite. Also the processing is also needed once, then the downstream systems contain the calculated counts.
Regarding the live partitioned stream I've used the windowing capabilities of kafka streams.